# VB.NET Getting Duplicate in Inserting data in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to insert data in MYSQL and get the latest ID but the problem is I'm Inserting Duplicate data
Is my syntax is wrong or something?

```
connection.Open()
insertString = "INSERT INTO `daily_report`(`saan_nalaman`,`purpose`, `usual_time`, `apps`,`feedback`,`userid`, `survey_at_what_blh`) VALUES ('" & txtq1.Text & "', '" & txtq2.Text & "', '" & txtq3.Text & "', '" & txtq4.Text & "', '" & txtq5.Text & "', '" & Utilities.UserID & "', '" & Login.RichTextBox1.Text & "');SELECT last_insert_id();"
command = New MySqlCommand(insertString, connection)
reader = command.ExecuteReader
connection.Close()
connection.Open()
TextBox1.Text = command.ExecuteScalar
connection.Close()
```

Comment: What do you thi9nk happens when you call `ExecuteReader`? What do you think happens when you call `Fill`? If you execute an `INSERT` statement twice, why be surprised that you get two records? Given that you want to retrieve one value, just call `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Can you check the edited question? I try using ExecuteScalr but its still Inserting duplicate data. Im newbie in VB sorry if i ask such a simple question

Comment: `VALUES` clause is empty in SQL text - but it must contain the data block with parameners placeholders.

Comment: no values are not empty

Comment: @JessTremblay: for your sake, do not write queries manually appending values, 'cause this can lead you to SQL injection! Use command parameters instead!

Comment: Okay thanks noted! But can you help me with my currrent problem? The inserting of duplicate data problem

Comment: You execute the very same command twice in `reader = command.ExecuteReader` and `TextBox1.Text = command.ExecuteScalar` so it's not so strange you get something duplicated. More: if you show us table definition maybe we can understand something more...

Comment: I'm trying to insert a data and display the last insert ID to a textbox

Comment: Execute **once**. Capture the result, display that. Tip: You don't need `;` in queries run via programmatic interfaces like this, that's the command separator. You have one command, no need for separation.

Comment: What @tadman is saying (he's absolutely correct) is to remove `reader = command.ExecuteReader; connection.Close();` part, because you don't really need them! Just execute the `command.ExecuteScalar` once.
By the way, code is definitely ugly, you should seriously change it...

Comment: its okay guys i did it thanks for the help

Comment: i used this   If reader.Read() Then
                    TextBox1.Text = reader.GetString(0)
                End If

Comment: by the way how do i make my code beautiful?

Comment: _how do i make my code beautiful?_: using queries with parameters as a start.
Then checking for possible errors during queries...

Comment: *"i used this If reader.Read()"*. You were only told multiple times to call `ExecuteReader` but why bother taking our advice? We're just the people you asked to help you in the first place.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: look at his response at SQL injection: _Okay thanks noted! But can you help me with my currrent problem?_ Well, honestly I would have thought about fixing my query immediately, then getting the correct result, but who am I to suggest such things?

Comment: @JessTremblay: I'm reading your query again... what if your user puts a ' in a textbox? I'm wondering if the query could end up being malformed...

Comment: the textbox is Visibility is set to false i just need to retrieve the Last selected ID

Comment: @JessTremblay The text boxes referred to by @Marco are the text boxes in your Insert. `txtq1.Text` etc. That is where sql injection or other errors can occur. Commonly where an apostrophe is in the text box. You should always be using Parameters.

Comment: oh okay i will user command parameters on that. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare and dispose your database objects in the method where they are used. `Using` blocks handle this for us even if there is an error. **Always** use parameters to avoid sql injection. Also, it makes the sql command easier to read and write without all the concatenation and single quotes. A single `ExecuteScalar` will accomplish both the insert and the select.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub GetID()
    Dim insertString = "INSERT INTO `daily_report`(`saan_nalaman`,`purpose`, `usual_time`, `apps`,`feedback`,`userid`, `survey_at_what_blh`) VALUES (@saan, @purpose, @time, @apps, @feedback, @userid, @survey) SELECT last_insert_id();"
    Dim id As Integer
    Using Command As New MySqlCommand(insertString, New MySqlConnection(ConStr))
        With Command.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@saan", txtq1.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@purpose", txtq2.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@time", txtq3.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@apps", txtq4.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@feedback", txtq5.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@userid", Utilities.UserID)
            .AddWithValue("@survey", Login.RichTextBox1.Text)
        End With
        Command.Connection.Open()
        id = CInt(Command.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    TextBox1.Text = id.ToString
End Sub
```